# setTimeout doesn't work when closure is included

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code...

```
 var string = 'qwe';

 document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    function bar(b){

       var a = string[b];
       if (a == 'q') {
          console.log('first');
       }
       if (a == 'w') {
          console.log('second');
       }
       if (a == 'e') {
          console.log('third');
       }

    }       
    setTimeout( bar(0), 1000 );
});
```

Problem is setTimeout doesn't work. Code executes right after clicking.

It's weird because if I avoid using the closure, it works...

```
setTimeout(function bar(){
   var a = string[0];
   //...everything else
},1000 );
```

But that would probably make the code messy/redundant, since I plan on doing it 3 times. Ideally the working code would be...

```
setTimeout( bar(0), 1000 );
setTimeout( bar(1), 2000 );
setTimeout( bar(2), 3000 );
```

But again, setting timeOut like this doesn't work for some reason :/ Any ideas why?

Comment: Use `setTimeout( () => bar(0), 1000 )` to queue a function. You just queue the **result** of the function.

Comment: Your executing the function immediately.  'bar(0)'.  Ironically creating a closure would help, but here you have just made a plain function.

Comment: Given `foo(bar())`, `bar` is always executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. This behavior doesn't magically change for `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( bar(0), 1000 );
```

over here setTimeout expects a function but it gets bar(0). hence while try to initialise bar(0) is called, you have to use

```
setTimeout( () => bar(0), 1000 )
```

to make it work, since now it is returning a function

Comment: Please look for duplicates for such basic questions. Answering a possible dupe can attract unwanted comments/votes

Comment: yes I see it is a possible duplicate of the question but it also answers why bar(0) was called immediately